# difflib: comparing a list of keywords with another list and returning ratio

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, difflib

I am trying to compare a list of words with a whole list of sentences using 'difflib'.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
s1 = ['okay', 'bye', 'what is'] # reference keywords

s2 = ['okay', 'what', 'dont worry', 'what is my name', 'is', 'my', 'name', 'bye'] #actual list

SequenceMatcher(a = s1, b = s2).ratio() # returns 0.36
```

The above snippet returns 0.36 as an overall result. But I would need a list where the reference keywords are matched with the actual list and the score is '1.0' for them. so in the above case, my result (for example - I am putting random scores here - the values could be [1.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0] . i.e. Exact match  = 1.0 , no match = 0.0, partial matches = scores accordingly.

Comment: Why are some of your entries `0`?  Shouldn't the second index have some ratio with `what is` in the first list?

Comment: @user3483203 yes, updated changes

Comment: Shoudn't `is` also match with `what is`? I think you need to review [mcve], because it seems completely random how you are computing these ratios.  For example, `don't worry` returns ratios of `[0.2857142857142857, 0.15384615384615385, 0.23529411764705882]` with your initial list, but you assign it `0`

Comment: @user3483203 yes, I updated the example with comments stating that the score are random, I gave them to just indicate context and did not intend to give the exact score.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
[max([SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio() for y in s1]) for x in s2]
>>> [1.0, 0.7272727272727273, 0.2857142857142857, 0.6363636363636364, 0.4444444444444444, 0.4, 0.2857142857142857, 1.0]
```

Comment: How can I remove the items (the text) which have a value of 1.0 in ur result, or even above a certain threshold. say, 0.3.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140245/remove-values-in-list-using-logical-operators)

Comment: I wanted to get the 'index' of the rows of text which is 1.0 and remove the text itself because it will be a match.